# Moving data between 2 tables on columns with different datatypes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I have 2 tables in 2 different databases. The first table (Custumers) Has many data with 10-12 coulmns.
Then I have the Second table(CustumersNew), it has new columns that should represent the same columns as Custumers just with different **names** and **datatypes**. CustumersNew is currently empty. I want to **move** all of the data from table Custumers to table CustumersNew.

The thing here is that table Custumers UserID column has the datatype *uniqueidentifier*
and the CustumerNew ID column has the datatype *int*. So as the rest of the coulmns, they sinply do not match in datatypes.

How do i move the data from A to B?

**EDIT:**
I'm using MS-SQL

Comment: So, How you would like to merge these data? for this `uniqueidentifier` customerid how would you like to get an id from it? generate a new one based on it or what? can you please add some sample data for that and list the fields and their data types this will be useful

Comment: Do you have option for executing external script on these databases? It could be very straightforward using scripting language like ruby.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `INSERT INTO CustumersNew(<column list>) SELECT <column list from Custumers CONVERTed to data types that match the data type of corresponding columns in CustumersNew> FROM Custumers` statement.

E.g.

```
INSERT INTO CustumersNew(UserId, Name, Age)
SELECT UserId, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), Name), CONVERT(INT, Age) 
FROM Custumers
```

I am assuming that Name and Age are of different types in these two tables. You would need to write a similar convert statements where the data type argument should match the data type in the CustumersNew table.

Since UserId/CustomerId being `uniqueidentifier` cannot be mapped to integer and I doubt the relevance of the values in this column from a functional perspective, I would model the UserId/CustomerId as an `AUTO`/`IDENTITY` column in the new table.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize `uniqueidentifier` is like a GUID and thought it's an auto-identity column. I updated my answer about how I would handle it and why. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer i have not tested ur solution but it should be okay now!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't store a `uniqueidentifier` in an `int` column so you'll have to come up with a new set of keys.

Most database systems provide a mechanism for sequentially numbering records with integer values. In SQL Server, they use `IDENTITY` columns, in Oracle they use `sequences`, I think that in MySql you specify the column as `auto_increment`.

Once you have set up your new table (with it's auto-numbering scheme) then simply insert the data using SQL:

`INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS_NEW (COL2, COL3, COL4) 
SELECT COL2, COL3, COL4 FROM CUSTOMERS`

Notice that the insert statement does not include the ID column - that should be populated automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are `not able to use insert` and `have to use update` it will be like this

```
UPDATE change 
SET    widget_id = (SELECT insert_widget.widget_id 
                    FROM   insert_widget 
                    WHERE  change.id = insert_widget.id) 
WHERE  change.id = (SELECT insert_widget.id 
                    FROM   insert_widget 
                    WHERE  change.id = insert_widget.id)
```

in this example, I wanted to move `widget_id` column form `insert_widget` table to `change` table, but change table already has data, so I have to use update statement