# Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 4 (Year)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting the conversion error when I try to import a text file to my database. Below is the error message I received:

Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 4 (Year).

Here is my query code:

```
CREATE TABLE Students
(
    StudentNo    Integer NOT NULL Primary Key,
    FirstName    VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    LastName     VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Year         Integer,
    GPA          Float NULL
);
```

Here is the sample data from text file:

```
100,Christoph,Van Gerwen,2011
101,Anar,Cooke,2011
102,Douglis,Rudinow,2008
```

I think I know what the problem is..Below is my bulk insert code:

```
use xta9354
bulk insert xta9354.dbo.Students
from 'd:\userdata\xta9_Students.txt' 
with (fieldterminator = ',',rowterminator = '\n')
```

With the sample data, there is no ',' after the Year attribute even tho there is still another attribute Grade after the Year which is NULL

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: It appears you are inserting 4 columns into a 5 column table. Are you using a format file? Depending on the formatting, it may be detecting extra ASCII characters at the end of your line.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try using a [format file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) since your data file only has 4 columns. Otherwise, try `OPENROWSET` or use a staging table.

`myTestFormatFiles.Fmt` may look like:

```
9.0
4
1       SQLINT        0       3       ","      1     StudentNo      ""
2       SQLCHAR       0       100     ","      2     FirstName      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR       0       100     ","      3     LastName       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLINT        0       4       "\r\n"   4     Year           "
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC45684.gif))</sub>

[This tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20170911131734/http://bidn.com:80/blogs/marcoadf/bidn-blog/2479/bulk-insert-format-file-skip-column) on skipping a column with `BULK INSERT` may also help.

Your statement then would look like:

```
USE xta9354
GO
BULK INSERT xta9354.dbo.Students
    FROM 'd:\userdata\xta9_Students.txt' 
    WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\myTestFormatFiles.Fmt')
```

Answer (score 21):

In my case, I was dealing with a file that was generated by hadoop on a linux box. When I tried to import to sql I had this issue. The fix wound up being to use the hex value for 'line feed' 0x0a. It also worked for bulk insert

```
bulk insert table from 'file' 
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a')
```

Comment: For some reason a terminator of '\n' was failing for me but '0x0a' works fine. Probably Unicode or codepage related

Answer (score 4):

We use the bulk insert as well. The file we upload is sent from an external party. After a while of troubleshooting, I realized that their file had columns with commas in it. Just another thing to look for...

Comment: This solved the problem for me, one of our import files had a numeric value of 1,012 which couldn't be converted to a number/decimal.

Comment: For this situation, I created a Python script to rewrite the file character by character, effectively converting commas to pipe characters, while leaving the commas found inside quotation marks. Then BULK INSERT could work.

Answer (score 3):

The above options works for Google big query file also. I exported a table data to goodle cloud storage and downloaded from there. While loading the same to sql server was facing this issue and could successfully load the file after specifying the row delimiter as

```
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
```

Pay attention to header record as well and specify

```
FIRSTROW = 2
```

My final block for data file export from google bigquery looks like this.

```
BULK INSERT TABLENAME
        FROM 'C:\ETL\Data\BigQuery\In\FILENAME.csv'
        WITH
        (
         FIRSTROW = 2,
         FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
         ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',--Files are generated with this row terminator in Google Bigquery
         TABLOCK
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Added MSSQLSERVER full access to the folder, diskadmin and bulkadmin server roles.

In my c# application, when preparing for the bulk insert command,

```
string strsql = "BULK INSERT PWCR_Contractor_vw_TEST FROM '" + strFileName + "' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n')";
```

And I get this error - Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 8 (STATUS).

I looked at my logfile and found that the terminator becomes ' ' instead of '\n'.
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error:

```
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)". Query :BULK INSERT PWCR_Contractor_vw_TEST FROM 'G:\NEWSTAGEWWW\CalAtlasToPWCR\Results\parsedRegistration.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', **ROWTERMINATOR = ''**)
```

So I added extra escape to the rowterminator - string strsql = "BULK INSERT PWCR_Contractor_vw_TEST FROM '" + strFileName + "' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', **ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n'**)";

And now it inserts successfully.

```
Bulk Insert SQL -   --->  BULK INSERT PWCR_Contractor_vw_TEST FROM 'G:\\NEWSTAGEWWW\\CalAtlasToPWCR\\Results\\parsedRegistration.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
Bulk Insert to PWCR_Contractor_vw_TEST successful...  --->  clsDatase.PerformBulkInsert
```

Comment: My BULKINSERT statement executes without error after adding the second backslash character to my ROWTERMINATOR but no data is inserted into the table.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is it's an encoding problem, for instance your file is UTF-8 but SQL will not read it the way it should, so it attempts to insert 100ÿ or something along these lines into your table.

Possible fixes:

1. Specify Codepage
2. Change the Encoding of the source using Powershell

Code samples:

```
1.
BULK INSERT myTable FROM 'c:\Temp\myfile.csv' WITH (
  FIELDTERMINATOR = '£',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
  CODEPAGE = 'ACP' -- ACP corresponds to ANSI, also try UTF-8 or 65001 for Unicode
);

2.
get-content "myfile.csv" | Set-content -Path "myfile.csv" -Encoding String
# String = ANSI, also try Ascii, Oem, Unicode, UTF7, UTF8, UTF32
```

Answer (score 0):

I was given data from Microsoft SQL and needed to import it to Azure SQL Edge.

I tried bcp, import data plugin for Azure Data Studio, bulk insert, but I always got some kind of an error that there was something wrong either with the file or with the data within.

What worked for me:

- Downloaded SQL Server Import and Export Wizard (comes together with SQL Server, better download 2019, as 2022 [errors out](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/error-with-my-sql-server-2022-preview-import-and-export-wizard/m-p/3689040/highlight/true#M2056))
- Imported data ([walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDnEBr9Wbeo)) in a new table within the same database. All the columns had nvarchar type
- Then I just copied the data from the new table to the destination table, [converting rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672150/moving-data-between-2-tables-on-columns-with-different-datatypes) along the way and [replacing `'null'` with `NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37842579/replace-null-string-with-null-value)

Answer (score 0):

My csv's blank columns had space character in blank cells after removing those out, it worked for me.
Here is the script I used for Bulk insertion:

```
BULK INSERT <table_name>
FROM '<file path>\\test.csv'
WITH
(
    FORMAT='CSV',
    FIRSTROW=2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
)
GO
```