# Ignore certain columns when using BULK INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, bulkinsert

I have a comma delimited text file with the structure

```
field1   field2   field3   field4
1        2        3        4
```

I wrote the following script to bulk insert the text file, but I wanted to leave out column 3

```
create table test (field1 varchar(50),field2 varchar(50),field4 varchar(50))
go
bulk insert test
from 'c:\myFilePath'
with 
(fieldterminator=',',
rowterminator='\n'
)
```

The insert worked fine, but the results of the insert made field4 look like
field3,field4, so the field 3 was actually just concatenated onto field4.  The flat files I'm working with are several gigs and can't be easily modified.  Is there a way to use bulk insert but have it ignore the columns that aren't declared in the create table statement?

Comment: First I tried to follow Charles Okwuagwu's advice and create view with columns I want to insert but it wouldnt work. Than I realise that column order in view has to be the same as in the table. It works now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a format file to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178129.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms179250.aspx

Or if you want a slightly cheekier way, just import it all and drop a column afterwards. ;)

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: The cheekier way is what I would suggest.

Comment: You can use format files in all versions of sql server, I just linked you the first things I found on google. 

I've used format files with SQL2000 to import product data and dropped about half the columns. 

I can find you some more specific examples if you want, or use your own google-fu.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way is to create a view that has just the columns you require.

Then bulk insert into that view.

Example:

```
create table people (name varchar(20) not null, dob date null, sex char(1) null)

--If you are importing only name from list of names in names.txt

create view vwNames as
select name from people

bulk insert 'names.txt'
```

Comment: I created a view with a single column but the single column got populated with all the columns from the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @CodingYoshi added an example

Comment: Thanks for the reply but no luck. I tried `create table people (name varchar(20) not null, dob date null, sex char(1) null)

create view vwNames as
select name from people`. Then `bulk insert vwNames from 'names.txt'
select name from vwNames` and it returns the full contents of the row. I have SQL Server 2012.

Comment: the idea is you have fewer columns in your source file than the table, you make a view that has the exact same number of columns as the file to be imported.

Comment: I see. However, in the question the OP said they wanted to leave out one of the columns in the text file (column 3 to be exact). Also, in your example you said `If you are importing only name` meaning leaving out some of the columns. This doesn't work if you have less columns in the table than the file. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 5):

you cant ignore a field while doing bulk insert , insted of doing that .. Load all 4 column and drop the colum which you dont want

```
create table test (field1 varchar(50),field2 varchar(50), field3 varchar(50),field4 varchar(50))
go
bulk insert test
from 'c:\myFilePath'
with 
(fieldterminator=',',
rowterminator='\n'
)

ALTER TABLE test DROP column [field3]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a temporary table and insert any data there. After that, you can do whatever you want with it.

```
CREATE TABLE #TmpTable(
    [CategoryId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentCategoryId] [int] NULL,
    [CategoryTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [AlternateName] [varchar](900) NOT NULL
)

BULK INSERT [dbo].[#TmpTable]
FROM 'C:\tmp\Categories.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'   --Use to shift the control to next row         
)

-- original table insert
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Categories]
( 
    CategoryId,
    ParentCategoryId,
    CategoryTypeId,
    Name,
    Code,
    AlternateName,
    IsDeleted,
    SystemCreated
)
SELECT 
    CategoryId,
    ParentCategoryId,
    CategoryTypeId,
    Name,
    Code,
    AlternateName,
    0,           -- custom value missed by file
    GETDATE()    -- custom value missed by file
FROM #TmpTable

-- remove tmp table
DROP TABLE #TmpTable
```

Answer (score -1):

You can indeed ignore certain data fields - see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-skip-a-data-field-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16):

Use a format file like here ([Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52ZGq.png)):
[image]

Essentially you map the unwanted source data field to column 0 in your table.
Yes FMT files are wierd see [this Stack Overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056929/bulk-load-data-conversion-error-type-mismatch-or-invalid-character-for-the-spec)
The fmt file maps data fields to columns by ordinal.
column 1 is the source data field order
column 6 is target table column ordinal.
These are 1 based numbered, and 0 means map to no column.