# Ignoring Columns at the end of Bulk Insert Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

What I'm doing is inserting into a table using bulk insert from a `csv`. There are fixed number of columns which I need to input.

**Code:**

```
BULK INSERT #TEMP FROM 'c:\temp.csv' 
WITH
(
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
, ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
, CODEPAGE = 'RAW'
,FIRSTROW =2
)
```

**Input:**

```
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C,D,E
```

**Problem:**

The column containing the values `E` are not to be written into the table because there is no column to store those values. When I take these values into the table, the last column is shown like this:

```
D,E
D,E
```

**Question:**

Is there any way to prevent the insertion of column `E` into the table without using a format file? I cannot use `OPENROWSET` to get these values as there are some permission issues.

Comment: I need the value `D` to be stored but the value `D,E` is being stored instead. I need to avoid that.

Comment: You're using a temp table;  can you add a column for e, then drop it after inserting?

Comment: There are a few answers to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711814/ignore-certain-columns-when-using-bulk-insert

Comment: The user enters values into the `csv` and then uploads it. After parsing the input, I'm getting the output. The `E` column shouldn't exist, but how do I determine if that is the wrong input or not?

Comment: I already checked that question out. That's why I mentioned in my question `without using a format file`. And the number of invalid columns maybe more than one.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you cant ignore a field while doing bulk insert. If you don't have access to the format file, then import into your temp table, and drop the columns you don't need.