# SQL or Powershell Bulk Insert Ignore first 3 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, bulkinsert

I have a question about Bulk Insert query.
I have a file which contains the following format

```
| |Test|test1|test2|
| | a  | b   |  c  | 
| | d  | e   | f   |
```

I use in sql the following code. I can skip the first row by using firstow=2 but is there something to ignore the first three characters from each row?

```
 SET @s = N'BULK INSERT ' + @t + '   FROM ''' + @f + '''
  WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|''  ,ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0a'',FIRSTROW=2 )'
```

In power shell you have something like this. Is there also something to ignore the first three characters?

```
  $columns = Get-Content $full | Select-Object -First 1
```

Comment: I recommend loading the data into a staging table and then moving the data to the final location.  This gives you the opportunity to fix types and adjust values.

Comment: Is there no other option like firstcharacter=3? because i need to import many files. To manually import it everytime is not really handy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore certain columns when using BULK INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711814/ignore-certain-columns-when-using-bulk-insert)