# Bulk insert with Blank values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table with 48 columns in which I want to import data from csv file. My csv file consist  of some blank values.

Whenever I uses bulk insert I am getting error:

> 1) Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (column name)
>
> 2)The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an
>   error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> 3)Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server
>   "(null)".

I am using sql server 2008

Below is bulk insert command I am using:-
**

```
bulk insert DataBaseName.dbo.TableName
from 'C:\FolderName\FileName.csv'
with
(
 FIRSTROW = 1,
 FIELDTERMINATOR =',',
 ROWTERMINATOR ='\n',
 KEEPNULLS
 )**
```

Please suggest how to handle it..?

Comment: have you check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056929/

Comment: No need to use format file for every time, we can directly dump data

Comment: What does the CSV look like.. does it have a header row?.. Can you try using the GUI import tools for your system? They can sometimes give better errors.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of errors make sure the below things:

1.The datalength should be matched according to  your .CSV file(use trial and error method and reach your lengths).

2. The number of columns should be matched(need to check manually).
3. The datatype conversions should be done implicitly(better to use all nvarchar datatype in order to avoid errors).

Comment: I have checked all those above points. but still getting same errors. Could you please suggest how to load blank value as NULL while importing table.

Comment: does your first row has column names? then rowheadder=1 and no need of allow nulls

Comment: Yes, First row has column names, In My CSV file there are more than 2 blank values comma separated for one record and there are many rows are like such.

Comment: your first row should have all values ,blank spaces are not allowed