# Replace null string with null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, null

I have a table that has a string value of 'null' that I wish to replace with an actual NULL value.

However if I try to do the following in my select

```
Select Replace(Mark,'null',NULL) from tblname
```

It replaces all rows and not just the rows with the string. If I change it to

```
Select Replace(Mark,'null',0) from tblname
```

It does what I would expect and only change the ones with string 'null'

Comment: Always specify (tag) the actual database you are using when you ask SQL questions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What?, no, that's not right, op wants the opposite of `COALESCE`

Comment: +1 for showing me something I had overlooked in the doco: "REPLACE returns NULL if any one of the arguments is NULL." It doesn't seem very logical when some values of `Mark` may not contain substring  `'null'`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `NULLIF`:

```
SELECT NULLIF(Mark,'null') 
FROM tblname;
```