# Bulk Insert failing in SQL Server "Column is too long"

Tags: sql-server, csv

I am trying to run the following command in SQL Server and its not working:

```
bulk insert dbo.Sales
from 'C:\Users\sram1\Downloads\SalesFile20161103\SALECOPY.TXT'
with 
(
    FIRSTROW = 1,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
)
```

Here is the error message that is printed:

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 1, Line 131
>   The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 131
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 131
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

I looked throughout StackOverflow, and saw that I should change the rowterminator, and I have tried both '0x0a' and '\r\n'. My data is tab separated, but it appears that in some cases, the tab is 2 spaces, other times it is more, other times it is less. Is this perhaps the root of the problem? If so, how do I fix it?

Comment: Is it tabs i.e. ascii char 9, or spaces? If the tabs have been converted to spaces, then it won't be finding any separators at all.

Comment: Possibly you will find an answer for your problem in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056929/bulk-load-data-conversion-error-type-mismatch-or-invalid-character-for-the-spec

Answer (score 1):

> My data is tab separated, but it appears that in some cases, the tab is 2 spaces

No a *tab character* can't be two spaces.  *tab separated* doesn't mean "data lines up when displayed on the screen".  It means there's an [ASCII tab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters) character between each column value.

If this is a one-time thing, you might import your data into Excel, and export it as tab-delimited.  If it's a regular thing, you'll want to learn how to examine the file to look for nonprinting characters, change line endings, and fix up delimiters.

HTH.