# SSIS package - Completed 100% with an error

Tags: ssis, bulkinsert, msbi

We are beginner of SSIS package. Now we trying to create the SSIS package which has Dynamic Source file name and MSSQL table as destination in Bulk Insert Task control flow.

*.csv file:

```
   policyID     statecode   county      eq_site_limit   hu_site_limit   fl_site_limit

   25           20191204    20191204    20191204        20191204        20191204
```

While running the package is completed `100%` with *Bulk Insert Task Error*. But we have data in destination. The screenshots are:

Execution Result:

[image: Execution Result]

Error Control Flow:

[image: Error Control Flow:]

Destination Table:

[image: Destination Table]

Reference Links:

1. [Bulk Insert Task](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4272/getting-started-with-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-parameters-vs-variables/) - ETL from flat file to DB table.
2. [Dynamic file name](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1084/dynamic-flat-file-connections-in-sql-server-integration-services/) - Create variable for dynamic file name.

Success and Error are occurred at same time means we are confused. So our questions:

As a SSIS developer, shall we don't care about the error? (Because Data has been transferred)

If no, what is reason and solution for that?

When searched in Google, some questions are found which are using SQL queries like [openrowset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056929/bulk-load-data-conversion-error-type-mismatch-or-invalid-character-for-the-spec) or [bulk insert](https://www.sqlnethub.com/blog/how-to-resolve-bulk-load-data-conversion-error-type-mismatch-or-invalid-character-for-the-specified-codepage/).

**Edit 1**

Delimiter values:

[image: Delimiter values]

**Edit 2**

Advance Properties: All columns have same except last column. Which has `{CR}{LF}`.

[image]

Thanks, 
Pugal.

Comment: On the Advanced tab, how do you have `policyID` defined?

Comment: @billinkc question has been updated.