# Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 - When reading table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I an creating a table `Dates` in Spark SQL. I am able to read the data when I do a select * on this newly created table `Dates` in the notebook.
However when I do a select * on this table in SQL server, it throws me the following error

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (DateColumn).

I have read that this happens when a bulk insert is being done where the SQL server tries to insert the table header into the columns and the data type mismatch occurs. However, this is a newly created table. How do I resolve this issue? Please suggest

Comment: Is the table defined an an External Data Source, by any chance?

Comment: How can I determine if the table is External? I am using Create Table in Spark SQL to create this table

Comment: @ThomA - so its a managed table and not an External Table.

Comment: Since it's happening at row 1, column 1... is the source data file UTF-8 encoded with a Preamble/Byte Order Mark? How have you configured the bulk load?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - In prod we are creating tables in the same manner as I am doing and writing into the same location. If I run the prod script from my notebook I am able to access the data from SQL. Thats what is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (DateColumn).

This error usually occurs when there is a type mismatch or invalid character in the data being inserted into the table.

**1st Method:** You can try using the configured **date** column to be "`smalldatetime`" instead of "datetime".

**2nd Method:** [Create a format file with bcp (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017&tabs=xml)

Since you mentioned you are using the new SQL server table, use a format file based on the data-type option specified **(-n, -c, -w, or -N)** and the table or view delimiters.

When you bulk import into a SQL Server table or bulk export data from a table, you can use a format file as a flexible system for writing data files.

Syntax:

```
USE <Database>
GO
BULK INSERT <Database>.dbo.Students
    FROM 'd:\userdata\xta9_Students.txt' 
    WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\myTestFormatFiles.Fmt')
```

**Reference:** [Use native format to import or export data (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-native-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Bulk load data using the COPY statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/quickstart-bulk-load-copy-tsql)

[Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 4 (Year)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056929/bulk-load-data-conversion-error-type-mismatch-or-invalid-character-for-the-spec)